# mysqli_query(): Empty query in /home/lucindabrummitt/public_html/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1924

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just uploaded a new plugin to my wordpress site and I got this warning:

mysqli_query(): Empty query in /home/lucindabrummitt/public_html/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1924

Usually if I have a problem, I can find answers on google but this one seems pretty particular and I'm not finding any info on it except for this forum.

I'm not terribly techie but if someone can tell me how to read this and how to change it I can follow directions pretty well.

Thanks All!

PS If I don't have the proper tags here could someone add the appropriate tags?

Comment: This error message won't help you find the cause. That's just where the incomplete `$sql` string turned up. The plugin is buggy and needs investigation instead.

Comment: Which new plugin did you upload?

Comment: linkmaster by Brett Rutecky I sent him a quick email about it.

Comment: @zipkundin linkmaster by Brett Rutecky I sent him a quick email about it, just haven't heard back yet and thought it was something I could fix myself.

Comment: @mario.. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @mario   plugin developer got back to me  and said  " its only a warning not an error (they are not the same thing)  Aks your hosting to turn off PHP warnings."  I feel like if I'm getting an error there is something wrong and turning off php warnings is kinda like turning up the stereo in your car so you don't here that strange noise coming from under the hood. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That kind of answer from a developer is not a good sign. Find another plugin, avoid using that one.

Comment: Yep, throw it out. Even though this particular case might be benign, it's a good indicator that SQL exploits might be lurking in there. If you want to investigate/fix, look for any `$wpdb->` occurences. One of them is badly patched together or entirely astray.

Comment: @cabrerahector yes that's what I did. $10 down the drain but at least my site won't break because of it. thanks for your support.

Comment: @mario. It had me really worried. I actually got an email from the developer - he told me to feel free to write my own plugin.  Now I just might take up coding.